# Enable and Disable Button in Pinput Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make it so that when the pin has been filled in, the button will be enabled and when removed, the button will be disabled again. However it happens only when the keyboard is already closed. The problem is also when the pin is removed, which was the enable button, it is still enabled so that it creates a gap that I didn't expect.

```
static inputPin({
      required BuildContext context,
      required String titleText,
      required NavigationView navigationView}) async {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final TextEditingController pinController = TextEditingController();
    bool isButtonEnabled = false;
    return showModalBottomSheet(
        useSafeArea: true,
        enableDrag: false,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        context: context,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Container(
            height: 600,
            padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                AppBarHelper.bottomSheet(context: context, buttonBack: true),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 40.0),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            titleText,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 55.0),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: width,
                            child: Pinput(
                              controller: pinController,
                              autofocus: true,
                              closeKeyboardWhenCompleted: false,
                              length: 6,
                              onCompleted: (pin) => isButtonEnabled = true,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                              followingPinTheme: PinTheme(
                                  height: 50.0,
                                  width: 50.0,
                                  textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.grey,
                                      fontSize: 30,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      border: Border.all(
                                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                                          width: 1.0))),
                              errorPinTheme: PinTheme(
                                  height: 50.0,
                                  width: 50.0,
                                  textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.grey,
                                      fontSize: 30,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      border: Border.all(
                                          color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.5),
                                          width: 1.0))),
                              defaultPinTheme: PinTheme(
                                  height: 50.0,
                                  width: 50.0,
                                  textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.grey,
                                      fontSize: 30,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      border: Border.all(
                                          color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
                                          width: 1.0))),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: CupertinoButton(
                          child: Text(
                            "SIMPAN",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                          onPressed: isButtonEnabled ? () {
                            BottomSheetHelper.verificationPin(
                                context: context,
                                titleText: "Konfirmasi",
                                requiredPin: pinController,
                                navigationView: navigationView);
                          } : null,
                          color: HexColor("#FFD700")),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

I've tried with the onCompleted section, I changed it to the value of "isButtonEnabled".
I hope that the keys can be enabled and disabled more dynamically without needing to close the keyboard first.

This is a screenshot of the pin page I created.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: Screenshot 3]

Comment: I would suggest use library. Rather than re-invent the wheels. Here are few libs.

https://pub.dev/packages/pin_code_text_field

https://pub.dev/packages/pin_view

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `onChanged` function instead `onCompleted` because `onChanged` call every time your pin code change and then you must check if pin has the length that i want then activate the button
your code must be like:

```
static inputPin({
  required BuildContext context,
  required String titleText,
  required NavigationView navigationView,
}) async {
  double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
  final TextEditingController pinController = TextEditingController();
  bool isButtonEnabled = false;
  return showModalBottomSheet(
    useSafeArea: true,
    enableDrag: false,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    context: context,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        height: 600,
        padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
        child: StatefulBuilder( // added
          builder: (context, setState) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                AppBarHelper.bottomSheet(context: context, buttonBack: true),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 40.0),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            titleText,
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 55.0),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: width,
                            child: Pinput(
                              controller: pinController,
                              autofocus: true,
                              closeKeyboardWhenCompleted: false,
                              length: 6,
                              // onCompleted: (pin) => isButtonEnabled = true, // removed
                              onChanged: (pin) => setState(() => isButtonEnabled = pin.length >= 6), // added
                              validator: (pin) {
                                if(pin != requiredPin.text) { 
                                 return 'PIN yang anda masukkan salah'; 
                                } 
                              }, // validator add
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                              followingPinTheme: PinTheme(
                                height: 50.0,
                                width: 50.0,
                                textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5), width: 1.0),
                                ),
                              ),
                              errorPinTheme: PinTheme(
                                height: 50.0,
                                width: 50.0,
                                textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.5), width: 1.0),
                                ),
                              ),
                              defaultPinTheme: PinTheme(
                                height: 50.0,
                                width: 50.0,
                                textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5), width: 1.0),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: CupertinoButton(
                        onPressed: isButtonEnabled
                            ? () {
                                BottomSheetHelper.verificationPin(
                                    context: context,
                                    titleText: "Konfirmasi",
                                    requiredPin: pinController,
                                    navigationView: navigationView);
                              }
                            : null,
                        color: HexColor("#FFD700"),
                        child: const Text(
                          "SIMPAN",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

and you must add `StatefulBuilder` that's allows you change your button state

Comment: Thank you sir, the repair code you provided is correct.
But I have another problem when I verify the pin, in the onChanged section I want not only to have all the PIN filled in, but an error message appears when the pin entered does not match.

validator: (pin) {
                                    if (pin == requiredPin.text) {
                                      isButtonEnabled = true;
                                    } else {
                                      return 'PIN yang anda masukkan salah';
                                    }
                                  },

Comment: You can use validator with onChanged you can keep isButtonEnabled in onChanged and you can verfy if pin != requiredPin.text and make it return   'PIN yang anda masukkan salah';

Comment: I update the answer with validator